# Vector problem solving: solving for possible values of $a, b, c, d, e, f, g$ for non-zero vectors $p, q, r, s$ given conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, solution-verification

For this question the non-zero vectors $p, q, r, s$ are such that:

$p = a(i + j)$

$q = 2i- bj$

$r = ci + dj$

$s=ei+fj$

I am to find the possible values of $a, b, c, d, e, f$ given that all of the following statements are true:

> • $p$ is perpendicular to $q$
>
> • magnitude of $p$ = magnitude of $q$
>
> • $q - 3r = 23i - 5j$
>
> • $s$ is in the same direction as $q$ but equal in magnitude to $r$

*What I have do so far:*

Since $p$ is perpendicular to $q$, the dot product $p·q$ equals $0$

$p = a(i + j)$ -> $p = ai + aj$

$q = 2i- bj$

$p·q = (a)(2) + (a)(-b)$

And so:

$0 = 2a -ab$

$0 = a(2-b) $

Therefore: $a = 0$ (but cancel out since none of vectors are zero vectors) or $b=2$

I calculated the magnitude of $p$ as $\sqrt2 a$ and magnitude of $q$ as $2+b$, but when I equate them and let $b = 2$ (from the previous calculation) I end up with the wrong value of $a$:

$\sqrt2 a = 2+b$

$\sqrt2 a = 2+2$

Therefore: $a = 2\sqrt2$

I am unsure how to proceed, any clues would be appreciated!

Comment: [WA](https://tio.run/##Jc5NCoNADAXg/RxFMkOrdKPkDoUuhyDRTqlQ2/kRUcSzT1O7@x6EvDfy9HQjT0PPOfsaNwbeGxVEJehOGIU93EVJ5OAh4ujYLi2sLdW4WHsmKlZrSyK9/tNypEZd4/CerLp9XrOzmzcB8QTeeMRgAgRdFRGlqgJ92SGZhBhNhON/gkByvYNs6kAmwK@cFOX8BQ) answer to check with.

Comment: magnitude of $q$ is not $2+b$

Answer (score 1):

$\lt p, q \gt$=$\lt a(i+j) , 2i-bj \gt$ = $\lt ai,2i \gt + \lt aj,-bj\gt$=$a(2-b)$=$0$

remember that all vectors are non-zero so a cannot be $0$ then $(2-b)=0$ ,$b=2$

also we know ||p||=||q|| which means $\lt p,p \gt = \lt q,q \gt$

||p||=a ,||q||=$\sqrt{4+b^2}=2\sqrt{2}$=a

$q-3r=2i-2j-3ci-3dj=(2-3c)i+(-2-3d)j=23i-5j \Rightarrow$ $23=2-3c ,5=2+3d$

$c=-7,d=1$

||s||=||r|| $\Rightarrow 50=e^2+f^2$  also

$\frac{q}{||q||}=\frac{s}{||s||}$ $\Rightarrow \frac{s}{||s||}=i-j ,s=||s||i-||s||j$

$||s||=\sqrt{e^2+f^2}=5\sqrt{2}$ ,$e=5\sqrt{2}  $

$f=-5\sqrt{2}$